# SQL Updating column after adding it giving "Invalid column name" error

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, ddl

I have the following SQL in SQL Server 2005 but I get an error stating "Invalid column name 'ExpIsLocalTime' (ln 7) when I run it:

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.columns WHERE Name = N'ExpIsLocalTime' AND Object_ID = Object_ID(N'[dbo].[tbl_SessionsAvailable]'))
BEGIN
    ALTER TABLE dbo.tbl_SessionsAvailable ADD
    ExpIsLocalTime bit NOT NULL CONSTRAINT DF_tbl_SessionsAvailable_ExpIsLocalTime DEFAULT (0)

    UPDATE  dbo.tbl_SessionsAvailable
    SET     ExpIsLocalTime = 1
END
GO
```

This will be in a script file that may be run more than once so I'm trying to make sure the `UPDATE` only runs once. Is there something about BEGIN/END that delays the execution of the DDL statement?

Comment: N'ExpIsLocalTime'   seems a strange notation .. are you sure is right?  (i'm not a sql-server expert)

Comment: @scaisEdge I believe that just designates it as a unicode string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your SQL query to do the `UPDATE` refers to a column that has not yet been created.  At compile time, SQL Server detects that the column does not exist, so it gives you the error "Invalid column name 'ExpIsLocalTime'".

In order to include the `UPDATE` in this query, you will need to encapsulate it in a dynamic SQL query.  In other words, something like this:

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.columns WHERE Name = N'ExpIsLocalTime' AND Object_ID = Object_ID(N'[dbo].[tbl_SessionsAvailable]'))
BEGIN
    ALTER TABLE dbo.tbl_SessionsAvailable ADD
    ExpIsLocalTime bit NOT NULL CONSTRAINT DF_tbl_SessionsAvailable_ExpIsLocalTime DEFAULT (0)

    DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(1000)
    SELECT @SQL = N'UPDATE dbo.tbl_SessionsAvailable SET ExpIsLocalTime = 1'
    EXEC sp_executesql @SQL
END
GO
```

We have the same issue in our SQL scripts that maintain tables.  After a table is created, if we add a column to it later, we have to use dynamic SQL to avoid these compilation errors.

Comment: Thanks, Paul. Is this a considered a compiler bug? If the dynamic SQL succeeds, the column is clearly there.

Comment: No, this is not a compiler bug.  SQL Server compiles the queries in the batch before running it.  If the column does not exist, the compilation fails with this error.

Answer (score 3):

Another possibly simpler solution is using the [GO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/sql-server-utilities-statements-go?view=sql-server-ver15) statement after the Alter statement.  This would send the DDL to the server.  Then run the rest of your SQL.  This should work if you are using sqlcmd osql or SSMS.

Comment: That won't run. That would split up the `BEGIN...END` block into two separate and invalid batches.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it's been a life-saver!